# Signalr with angular and .net core error with code 1006

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, websocket, asp.net-core-signalr

I am facing problem with the signalr when hosting angular application on the IIS it keeps showing the following error on the console:

```sh
[2020-05-31T08:09:00.838Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ().'.
```

keeping in mind that once I have hosted the angular application using nodeJs it works fine, yet I need to host the angular application on IIS.

I am using "@microsoft/signalr" and aspcore 3.1

My code sample angular:

```sh
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
    //establish a new connection on the logging user group
    this.signalRConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
      .withUrl(this.hubUrl)
      .build();
    this.signalRConnection.start().then(() => {
      this.session.id = this.signalRConnection.connectionId;
      this.signalRConnection.send("RegisterOnlineUser", this.session, 'title', 'url');
      this.signalRConnection.send("GetOnlineUsers");
    });
  }
```

aspcore :

```sh
        public async void registerOnlineUser(SessionInfo session)
        {

            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, session.group);

          await Clients.Group(Users).SendAsync("RegisterOnlineUser", session);


            }
```

Comment: What kind of library are you using for signalr in frond end? and is your backend nodejs or else ?

Comment: You need to share angular and core part codes to understand problem

Comment: I am using the "@microsoft/signalr" from the front end for the angular, and my backend is  asp.net core 3.1

Comment: @aspnet/signalr is suitable for core api . In my applications I use this library for angular

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable websocket in IIS settings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket